# Oracle - JPA Alter Constraint

Tags: oracle, jpa, foreign-keys, constraints

I'm having a problem with a constraint in oracle/jpa mapping.
I have these 4 tables

```
 SucursalSolicitanteFornecimento(
    Sucursal_ID (NUMBER) PK
    Sucursal_Name(VARCHAR)
    Sucursal_UF

 );

 ParamSolicitante(
   paramID (NUMBER) 
   paramName(Varchar)


);

 ConfiguracaoParametroSolicitante(
      paramConfigID (NUMBER) PK,
      paramID FK (from ParamSolicitante),
      requestID (From SucursalSolicitanteFornecimento)


);


 ConfiguracaoParametroSolicitanteSucursal(
          ID (NUMBER) PK,
          paramConfigID FK from ConfiguracaoParametroSolicitante,
          SucursalSolicitanteFornecimento_ID
          SucursalSolicitanteFornecimento_UF  - Both From      SucursalSolicitanteFornecimento


 );
```

My problem is when I try to insert a new value in ConfiguracaoParametroSolicitanteSucursal I can't have 2 different ParamConfigID with the same SucursalSolicitanteFornecimento_UF and same SucursalSolicitanteFornecimento_ID because of the FK. 
But now that's exactly what I need, more than one parameter for that SucursalSolicitante on the same state.

My Java class is mapped this way:

```
public class ConfiguracaoParametroSolicitanteSucursal{
@Id
@GeneratedValue()
private Integer codigoConfigParamSolctteSuc;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns( { @JoinColumn(name = "SUCURSAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "SUCURSAL_ID", nullable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "SUCURSAL_UF", referencedColumnName = "SUCURSAL_UF", nullable = false) })
private SucursalSolicitanteFornecimento sucursalParametro;

@JoinColumn(name = "paramConfigID", referencedColumnName = "paramConfigID", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private ConfiguracaoParametroSolicitante configuracaoParametroSolicitante;

}
```

What can I do to achieve what I need? I was wondering if I have to change @OneToOne column to @ManyToOne and Delete the Constraint on my Database.

Comment: Another thing that came into my mind, it is possible to use the column configuracaoParametroSolicitante ( paramConfigID ) as part of the FK? If so, how can I do that in JPA?